# Select last 3 month Record in Month January based on User Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I has a record in database as below

```
ID        RDate       Name
 1         1/1/2015     A
 2         1/1/2015     B
 3         31/12/2014   A
 4         3/12/2014    A
 5         22/10/2014   C
 6         1/8/2014     D
```

I wish to select current month record and last 3 month record base on current date.

I has query as below

```
Select * from tbl1 where month(RDate) = Month(getdate()) and Year(RDate) = Year(getdate())
```

This I can get current month record.  I can get last month record use below query

```
Select * from tbl1 where month(RDate) = Month(Dataadd(month, -1, RDate)) and  Year(RefDate) = Year(DateAdd(year, -1, RDate))
```

The problem is when current month is April 2015, my last 3 month record will be March 2015, Feb 2015 and Jan 2015.  The query for Year will be in-correct because the year is minus 1 in the query.  How I can make the query dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dateadd` and `datediff` functions

`dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-3, 0)` gives start of current month - 3 months

above will give Oct 1 2014 if it is run today.

`dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), -1)` gives previous month last day

above will give Dec 31st 2014 if it is run today.

```
select * from Table1
where RDate between
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-3, 0),
AND 
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
    ID      INT,
    RDate   DATE,
    Name    VARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES
(1, '20150101', 'A'),
(2, '20150101', 'B'),
(3, '20141231', 'A'),
(4, '20141203', 'A'),
(5, '20141022', 'C'),
(6, '20140801', 'D');

SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE
    (
        RDate >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -- First day of the current month
        AND RDate < DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0) -- First day of the next month
    )
    OR (
        RDate >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0) -- 3 months less than the current month
        AND RDate < DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  -- First day of the current month
    )
DROP TABLE tbl1
```

Of course you can combine the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    RDate >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0) -- 3 months less than the current month
    AND RDate < DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0) -- First day of the next month
```

For more common date routines, see this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/

Answer (score 0):

Compare the results of the first and second query. If you want the data for this month and the last 3 FULL calendar months, then use the second query.

```
declare @t table (ID int, RDate date, Name char)
```

insert into @t
values
    (1,'2015-01-01','A'),
    (2,'2015-01-01','B'),
    (3,'2014-12-31','A'),
    (4,'2014-12-03','A'),
    (5,'2014-10-22','C'),
    (6,'2014-09-01','D'),
    (7,'2014-09-06','D'),
    (8,'2014-09-05','D'),
    (9,'2014-08-01','D')

declare @comparison_date date = '2015-01-06'

select * 
from @t
where RDate > dateadd(month,-4,@comparison_date)

select * 
from @t
where RDate > dateadd(month,-4,dateadd(day,-datepart(dd,@comparison_date),@comparison_date))